# resValue under buildTypes produces No resource found that matches the given name

Tags: android, apk, build.gradle, manifest, signed-apk

This is my build.gradle

```
buildTypes {
        debug {
           resValue "string", "facebook_app_id", "\"XXXXXXXXX\""
        }
        live{
           resValue "string", "facebook_app_id", "\"XXXXXXXXX\""
        }
}
```

and this my manifest file where I use facebook_app_id

```
<meta-data
     android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
     android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
```

this works fine while debugging but when generating a signed apk this error produced

No resource found that matches the given name (at 'value ' with value '@string/facebook_app_id').

Answer (score 1):

goto -> res->values->string.xml open that file and write

```
<string name="facebook_app_id">Facebook</string>
```